# How to load xsd schema, create classes from it then initialize objects with data from DB an convert it to xml in Rails7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xsd, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to load large xsd schema from URL/file. My idea is something like load schema and create classes from it then initialize objects with data from my DB and lastly convert objects to xml structure. Is there a way to do it automatically, because in my case xsd schema can change during the year and also I need all version of that xsd schemas... User will be able to select from some selectbox which schema will be used for generating xml. For this reason, I would not like to do it manually because I will have to create new classes every time when the schema will be updated.

Now I am using gem 'soap4r-ng' and it works fine when it comes to creating classes but convert objects to xml is a bit tricky part.
One of the generated class is for example:

```
class Identification
  attr_accessor :number
  attr_accessor :street
  attr_accessor :tel
  attr_accessor :email

  def initialize( number = nil, street = nil, tel = nil, email = nil)
    @number = number
    @street = street
    @tel = tel
    @email = email
  end
end
```

When I initialize object and call to_xml gives me undefined method to_xml for example:

```
identification=Identification.new("23","Abbey Road","0928383893","name@email.com")
identification.to_xml
```

So for each class, I would have to define to_xml method, which I would not want, since every time I generate new classes according to the current xsd scheme, I would have to manually add it to each class.
Is there any way to solve this using another gem for example?

Comment: Are all the objects defined in that fashion, meaning a list of instance variables? If so could implement something simple like `module XMLSerializer; def self.to_xml(obj); obj.instance_variables.to_h {|i_var| [i_var.to_s[1..],obj.instance_variable_get(i_var)]}.to_xml;end;end` then `XMLSerializer.to_xml(identification)`

Comment: This is going to be very difficult to implement in ActiveRecord as in AR the database schema mostly decides the attributes of the models and not vice versa. Additionally converting objects to XML is subject to its own kind of impedence mismatch problem as XML is document based. I guess my main point here is that this is not a trivial problem to solve and Rails might not be the best choice.

Comment: I mean on the face of it most of these problems seem kind of solvable the first run around - parse a XSD and then somehow bridge the gap between that and the SQL world. Then pull data out of the database and serialize it into XML using some kind of schema. Where it goes crazy is if you want to pull the schema multiple times a year and repeat the process automatically and support multiple schemas as output. I don't want to be too discouraging but you and your employeer should be aware that this sounds like a pretty massive undertaking.